# Mvc 3 texbox in webgrid (razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid

Simple Q:How do you I get the textbox to show the value. Code below fail on item.LastName

```
@model List<Mvc2010_11_12.Models.Employee>
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model,defaultSort: "FirstName",rowsPerPage: 3);
}

<div id="grid1">
    @grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("LastName"),
        grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.TextBox("LastName", item.LastName))
    ))
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Extension methods (i.e., Html.TextBox) don't work well with dynamic objects (i.e., item)... it's a limitation of c#.

You've got a few options:

format: `InputExtensions.TextBox(Html, "Last Name", item.LastName) // static call`

format: `Html.TextBox("Last Name", (object)item.LastName) // cast as non-dynamic object`

format: `&lt;input type="text" name="LastName" value="@item.LastName" /&gt; // avoid extensions`

Also, I believe there's an inherent lambda with an "item" parameter - you shouldn't need to declare this yourself.

Comment: I have taking the question to the blog of the presenter of the code I am modifying (Shiju Varghese). I think we need so guidance on best practice.

Answer (score 3):

Quite convoluted but works:

```
@helper TextField(Employee employee, HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<Employee>> html)
{
    @html.TextBoxFor(x => employee.LastName)
}

<div id="grid1">
    @grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("LastName"),
        grid.Column(format: item => TextField(item.Value, Html))
    ))
</div>
```

Maybe there's a better approach though. Still learning the Razor syntax and quite frankly I am a bit disappointed by the WebGrid helper after having used [MVCContrib Grid](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid&ProjectName=mvccontrib).

Comment: There most be a easier way a doing it.

Comment: @user408698, I hope there is but I am a bit skeptical.

Comment: Using this approach, when that form with textboxes is submitted back to a HttpPost action, how do you know which value belongs to which record?

Comment: @Boris B, you could include an additional hidden input containing the record id.

Comment: I guess that means something like `hidden id="RowId{N}" <=> textbox id="LastName{N}", N=1..RowCount`. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

That one works for me

```
@model List<Mvc2010_11_12.Models.Employee>
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model,defaultSort: "FirstName",rowsPerPage: 3);
}

<div id="grid1">
    @grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("LastName"),
        grid.Column(format: @<span>@Html.TextBox("LastName",@item.LastName as object)</span>   )
    ))
</div>
```

Comment: How to save the values from the textbox column in webgrid to a table in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.TextBox("LastName", (object) item.LastName))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to cast object to string as follows:

```
format: (item) => Html.ActionLink(
    (item.AppCode as object).ToString(),
    "Index",
    "ApplicationHealthCheck",
    new { Code = item.AppCode },
    null),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
grid.Column("AmountValue", header: "Amount", format:@<text><input name="Amount" type="text" value="@item.AmountValue"</text>)
```

Comment: i want to add dynamic textbox column with this bt it is not editable..ie i m unable to enter any value in this textbox

Answer (score 0):

Showing Link or plain text based upon a condition:

```
grid.Column(format: (dbItem) => dbItem.QtyCompleted == 0 ?
                 Html.ActionLink(
                 "Start Setup",
                 "SaveData", 
                 "Workorder",
                 new
                   {
                       msid = dbItem.MSID,
                       qtyCompleted = 0, 
                       serialNum = "ABC"
                   },
                 new 
                   { 
                       onclick = "return ConfirmAction('Start Setup');" 
                   }) :
                 Html.Label(((DateTime)dbItem.StartTime).ToShortDateString())
            )
```