# How to make a MVC 3 Webgrid with checkbox column?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

The code below will insert an actionlink into one of the web grids' columns.

```
    @{
    View.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    var usersGrid = new WebGrid(source: Model,
        rowsPerPage: 40);
}
@usersGrid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "grid",
        headerStyle: "head",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                columns: usersGrid.Columns(
                    usersGrid.Column(format: (item) => 
                         Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id})),
                    usersGrid.Column("Surname")
        )
    )
```

But if i exchange that line for this:

```
                usersGrid.Column(format: (item) => Html.CheckBox(item.Id)),
```

I get this error:

> Error 4   The best overloaded method
>   match for
>   'System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid.Column(string,
>   string, System.Func,
>   string, bool)' has some invalid
>   arguments.

I don't quite understand the difference between the two.. why does one work and the other error?

The ultimate goal is to be able to tick a number of check boxes and then send to print their info.

Comment: See that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195440/mvc-3-texbox-in-webgrid-razor/4564506#4564506

Comment: [This will help you](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/09/13/webgrid-helper-with-check-all-checkboxes.aspx)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is what worked for me in the end.

```
usersGrid.Column(header: "Print?", format: @<text><input name="Prints" 
      type="checkbox" value="@item.ID" /></text>),
```

Got to give thanks to Nick Harris, answer found in the comments of his blog here:
http://www.nickharris.net/2010/10/a-first-look-at-the-asp-net-mvc-3-webgrid/

Comment: Good tip, if you have a boolean value to check it you can add an additional condition as well
usersGrid.Column(header: "Header", format: @<text><input name="HasFormgivaren" type="checkbox" value="@item.ID" @(item.IsChecked == 1 ? "Checked" : null) /></text>),

Answer (score 5):

this is working for me:

```
grid.Column("SiparisNo", "Seç", format: (item) => Html.CheckBox(String.Format("Secili_{0}", (int)item.SiparisNo), false, new { @style = "width:60px;" }))
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to beware of using extension methods (Html.*) with dynamics (item)... it doesn't work well in csharp.  When you do the new {} projection or call ToString, it's no longer dynamic.  Alternatively, you could cast: (object)item.Id.

Comment: Thanks, i'll get the chance to try this later today.

Comment: Does this mean in vb it's handled better? just asking hehe :)

Comment: I'm no VB expert, but I think it's a non-issue for VB. I believe dynamics are just cast as objects there.  Csharp does runtime binding of dynamics, but can't resolve extension methods at that time.

Answer (score 2):

`usersGrid.Column(format: (item) => Html.CheckBox((string)item.Id)),`

this should work

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way:

```
usersGrid.Column(format: (item) => Html.CheckBox("Id"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because the CheckBox call is not returning the same datatype that ActionLink is returning.

This is what you do. Do a message box call on the action link call and the check box call with same arguments, rap each inside the function call TypeName() and display the results in a msgbox for u to see. Also, do a .ToString in both as well, now, look at the results, it should tell you if there is a discrepancy between the datatypes returned, if you can, post the results, and I can tell you more. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks, i'll get the chance to try this later today.

Comment: @kohan ok, let me know how it goes when you do, am interested myself now lol cheers mate

Comment: Don't think the problem was with the checkbox but the dynamic item (which is what chenriks was getting at i think). But anyway, i have sorted it now. Many thanks!

Comment: @kohan nevertheless, it was because of a datatype return discrepancy, right? did you try the TypeName and tostring methods to get at it or where you just returning the wrong datatypes to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

After a vigorous search I found an optimal solution, you can use this logic instead if you're finding difficult to use HTML helpers.

```
grid.Column(header: "", format: @<text><input name="chkBox" type="checkbox" value="@item.Id" @(item.Id == false ? null : "checked") /></text>)
```

Answer (score 0):

grid.Column("ID", "Select", format: (item) => Html.CheckBox((string)item.ID, false, new { @style = "width:60px;" }), canSort: false)

This is working perfect.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
new HtmlString(usersGrid.Column(format: (item) => Html.CheckBox(item.Id)).ToString()),
```

instead of

```
usersGrid.Column(format: (item) => Html.CheckBox(item.Id)),
```

Answer (score -3):

**

```
@{
  var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model.ToList(), canPage: true, canSort: true);
  grid.Pager (WebGridPagerModes.All);
}
```

**

```
<div id="g1">
    @grid.GetHtml(

    columns:grid.Columns
    (grid.Column(columnName:"paymentno",header:"PAYMENT NO"),

    grid.Column(columnName:"mname",header:"NAME"),

    grid.Column(columnName:"pamt",header:"AMOUNT"),

    grid.Column(header: "Header", format: @<text><input name="HasFormgivaren" type="checkbox" 
        value="@item.checkresult" @(item.checkresult == "True" ? "Checked" : null) /></text>)
    )
    )
</div>
```

Comment: You should add some explanation too