# Razor MVC 3 RC2 - WebGrid Actionlink with Dynamic Text

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm outputting an Actionlink, in a WebGrid, with Dynamic link text and the only way I can get it to work is as follows:

```
Grid.Column(header: "Subject", columnName: "Message.Subject", format:(item) => Html.ActionLink(((object)item.Message.Subject).ToString(), "Message", new {Id = 12345 }))
```

Does anyone have a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 7):

Not much different.

```
Grid.Column(
    header: "Subject",
    columnName: "Message.Subject",
    format: (item) => Html.ActionLink(
        (string)item.Message.Subject, "Message", new { Id = 12345 }
    )
)
```

See: [How to make a MVC 3 Webgrid with checkbox column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306683/how-to-make-a-mvc-3-webgrid-with-checkbox-column)