# Using data in a HTML.ActionLink inside a WebGrid.column, not possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I have the following WebGrid in my ASP.NET MVC3 test application. It displays a list of customers:

```
@grid.GetHtml(
tableStyle: "grid",
headerStyle: "head",
alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
columns: grid.Columns
         (
         grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Details", new { id = item.id })),
         grid.Column("Address.CompanyName"),
         grid.Column("Address.City")
         )
)
```

The interesting part here is the Edit-link I've added in the first column. I would like to use the customers account number instead of the plain "Edit"-test. However, it causes me a great deal of problems to do so.

I've tried:

```
grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink(item.AccountNumber.ToString(), "Details", new { id = item.id })),
```

However, it seems like there is something i don't understand about how this works because i keep getting this exception:

```
CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid.Column(string, string, System.Func<dynamic,object>, string, bool)' has some invalid arguments
```

Can anyone explain to me why this isn't working? What is the difference between "Edit" and `item.AccountNumber.ToString()` (apart from the spelling)?

I should note that the link works when using the "Edit"-text, and that `AccountNumber` is a long.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is an example of how I do it with a date.

```
grid.Column(columnName: "Date", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink(((string)item.Date), "Edit", new { id = item.id })),
```

> You have to beware of using extension
>   methods (Html.*) with dynamics
>   (item)... it doesn't work well in
>   csharp. When you do the new {}
>   projection or call ToString, it's no
>   longer dynamic. Alternatively, you
>   could cast: (object)item.Id.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306683/how-to-make-a-mvc-3-webgrid-with-checkbox-column).

Comment: You've got it spot on! Thanks! If i used "(string)(item.AccountNumber.ToString()) it works... not quite sure why i need to cast it to a string though? I guess ToString() returns a string?

Comment: I "think" item is dynamic so it doesn't have that method?

Answer (score 5):

Just in case any one was wondering about how it should look in VB here is an example:

```
grid.Column("PersonID", "Admin", Function(modelItem) Html.ActionLink("View", "Details", New With {.id = modelItem.PersonID}))
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case Derek Beattie solution is not working.

And I use this

```
 grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }), style: "column-action")
```

Answer (score 1):

My columns were being generated in the Model, where Html.ActionLink seems inaccessible. So I had to create the href and return it as an MvcHtmlString. This is what I ended up doing,

```
new WebGridColumn{ColumnName="FileName", Header= "File",
                Format = item => new MvcHtmlString("<a href='" + item.FileLink + "'>" + item.FileName +"</a>")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved like this

`grid.Column("Id", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink((string)item.id.ToString(), "Edit", new { id = item.id }))`

Answer (score 0):

I use following code for grid. It working for me.

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column(header: "Serial No", format:@<text><div>@(item.WebGrid.Rows.IndexOf(item) + 1)</div></text>),
        grid.Column(columnName: "Stdname", header: "Student Name"),
        grid.Column(header: "Email ID", format:@<text><a href="mailto:@item.Email">@item.Email</a></text>),
        grid.Column(header: "EDIT",format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID })),
        grid.Column(header: "DETAILS", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID })),
        grid.Column(header: "DELETE", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID }))
))
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns => {
    columns.Add(c => c.ConsumerNo).Titled("Consumer No").SetWidth(70).Filterable(true);
    columns.Add(c => c.ConsumerName).Titled("Consumer Name").SetWidth(200).Filterable(true);
    columns.Add(c => c.MobileNo).Titled("Mobile No").SetWidth(70).Filterable(true);
    columns.Add(c => c.Address).Titled("Address").SetWidth(200).Filterable(true);
    columns.Add(c => c.AreaName).Titled("Area Name").SetWidth(70).Filterable(true);
    columns.Add(c => c.StaffName).Titled("Staff Name").SetWidth(100).Filterable(true);
    columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).Titled("INSPECT").SetWidth(60).RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("INSPECT", "InspForm", new { id = o.UniqueConsumerId, style = "background-image:url('~/Images/orderedList1.png')" }));                       
}).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 grid.Column("GiftID",canSort:false, format: (item => Html.ActionLink((string)(@item.GiftID).ToString(), "Edit", new { GiftID = @item.GiftID })))
```

Comment: This answer does not help to answer the question. It provides a solution and the syntax appears to be correct but you should further explain why you would use this solution and attempt to answer the question and or explain why you would use this solution and why the previous syntax was not working.