# What does "(item) =>" do?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to learn C# and MVC3. I wanted to have a WebGrid column as an Html.Action link, however, it wouldn't work until I did this:

```
grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }))
```

So I know that this fixes it but why? The (item) looks like a cast but what is the => for? From reading other questions I see that it's evidently bad to do this for some reason - why?

Comment: It is not bad at all to use lambdas.

Comment: It's not bad to do this.

Comment: Thanks guys. The answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167903/using-data-in-a-html-actionlink-inside-a-webgrid-column-not-possible) question is what had me worried.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is known as a lambda expression / anonymous function in C#.  The `()` portion is the argument list and the `=>` indicates the right hand side is the body / expression of the lambda.

Here's a slightly expanded form which may be a bit clearer

```
Func<ItemType, string> linkFunction = (item) =>
{
  return Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id });
};
```

Comment: I think you can drop the "/ anonymous function". Just lambda expression is more correct I think.

Comment: @justin.m.chase anonymous function is more encompassing because it covers both lambda expressions and anonymous methods

Answer (score 7):

That would be a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).  And no, using lambda's is not bad, it's a (very) good thing.

Comment: @RichK: I upvoted the answer but removed "MSDN is your friend" because it added a condescending tone to an otherwise excellent answer.

Comment: Ah, it looks like I may have stomped out Claus's extra sentence there with my original edit. Sorry about that :)