# How would I go about displaying data from one view in another view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net-entity-data-model

Sorry for the confusing title, i'm having trouble trying to explain what I am trying to achieve. I have a view, that currently displays 'Trips' from my database (Destination, Type, Price etc). I have used an actionlink and my aim is to be able to select a trip, click the actionlink and be taken to a 'booking' page. The booking page will display the information for the actionlink selected, and I will add a drop down list to select the number of people going on the trip.

What is the best way to achieve this? Would a session be viable here? I'm completely new to MVC and am still trying to wrap my head around the way it works! Thanks in advance to anyone who reads this!

[image: actionLink]

TripController code -

```
namespace WebApplication5.Controllers
{
public class TripController : Controller
{
    // GET: Trip
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        List<Trips> trips = new List<Trips>();
        using (SampleModel dc = new SampleModel())
        {
            trips = dc.Trips.ToList();
        }
            return View(trips);
    }
    public ViewResult Booking()
    {

        return View();
    }
}
}
```

TripsModel code -

```
[Table("Trips")]
public partial class Trips
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int TripID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Destination { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public int? Price { get; set; }
}
```

Trip ListView code -

```
@model List<WebApplication5.Models.DB.Trips>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "List of trips";
var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 10);
grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);
}

<h2>List of Trips</h2>

<div id="content">
@grid.GetHtml(
            tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
            headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
            footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
            alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
            rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
            columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column(columnName: "TripID", header: "TripID"),
                grid.Column(columnName: "Destination", header:     "Destination"),
                grid.Column(columnName: "Type", header: "Type"),
                grid.Column(columnName: "Price", header: "Price"),               
                grid.Column(columnName: "Book", format: (item) =>     Html.ActionLink("Book", "Booking", new { id = item.TripID }))
                ))

</div>
```

TripBookingView code -

```
@model WebApplication5.Models.DB.Trips
```

Comment: A link instead of a radio button would make this easier, but with you current UI, you need to handle the `.click()` event of the button and build a url to the method you want to redirect to (including the value of the selected radio button which would be the ID of the `Trip`) and then use `location.href = yourUrl;`

Comment: How will a link make it easier, and what would I need to change to replace the radio buttons with links? Thanks @StephenMuecke

Comment: Because it can simply be `@Html.ActionLink("Book", "Booking", new { id = item.TripID })` (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167903/using-data-in-a-html-actionlink-inside-a-webgrid-column-not-possible) for more detail)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am still not able to get it working this way, even after reading through the answer you provided. I have created a booking view, added the return View() for the booking class but the Booking view doesn't show the trip that was selected on the previous page!

Comment: I'm not psychic and cannot guess what errors you have in your code. Edit your question showing what you tried (and delete all the irrelevant code such as your css - and we only need to see one of 2 properties - [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hi Stephen, I have edited my question to show it at its current state. I don't currently have any errors, I am now just trying to get the action link pressed on the gridview to display that trips details on the TripBooking view. I have tried various pieces of code in both the TripController and the Booking view but nothing has worked thus far. Do you have any ideas on how I can achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138702/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-acostea).

Answer (score 0):

so the simplest idea is to write a script function like

```
 @section scripts{
<script>
$(function(){
$('#book').on('click',function(){
 windows.location.href('@url.ActionLink('Booking','Trip',new{price = price}))
})
})
<script>
}
```

and in the Controller side

```
public Task ActionResult Booking(int price)
{
//Do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving Button outside you can render the button/ link in each row of the grid as below

```
@grid.GetHtml(columns: new [] {
grid.Column(
"",
header: "Actions",
format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Book", "Book", new { id=item.TripID})</text> ) });
```

and in controller change your controller to

```
public ActionResult Book(int TripID)
{
  //bring required data from DB for the TripID you received
}
```