# How pass list<object> into webgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I'm trying to put into webgrid collection

```
public class MyClass()
{
    List<Row> rows {get; set;}
}

public class Row()
{
    public string code {get; set;}
}

grid.Column("Amount",
format: @<text>
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.rows.FirstOrDefault().code, new { @class = "edit-mode", size = 5 })
</text>),
```

Using `model.rows.FirstOrDefault().code` it works but returns first element of collection in each row.

`model.rows.GetEnumerator().Current.code` returns nothing

How to get right desision to get each element of collection in own row

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx

Comment: There is the fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195440/mvc-3-texbox-in-webgrid-razor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Source:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195440/mvc-3-texbox-in-webgrid-razor)

Used this format: InputExtensions.TextBox(Html, "Last Name", item.LastName) // static call